# Android browser: fill vertical viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, android-webview

I have a web app that I want to exactly vertically fill the browser viewport, including pushing the address bar up past the top.

Is there some way of getting the browser viewport size without the address bar? Currently, I am using jQuery like:

```
$("#mainBox").height($(window).height)
```

but this will fill the viewport minus the address bar, causing the element to be too narrow when viewed in landscape.

For iPhone, I was getting around this by hard-coding the iPhone browser viewport sizes into the page, but there are obvious problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the height in an oerintationchange event. So is you create an orientationchange event handler for the window you need to call the same line inside that handler and you will get the new window height and you should be good.